# How can I output only half the entries in a loop?

Tags: templating, forloop

I'm building a Craft website on Bootstrap 5.
I want to split the output of a loop evenly across 2 seperate columns.
There is an image column in the middle so the loop can't be continuos.
The amount of items in the loop will vary so I need a flexible solution.

This is my current twig setup which outputs all entries in the table.

```
                {% for q in tableItem %}
                <div class="d-flex mb-5 table-item" data-aos="fade-up"> 
                    <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                    {% for asset in q.icon %}
                    <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-4">
                    <h5 class="mb-2">{{q.heading}} </h5>
                    <p>{{ q.description }}</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the special `loop` variable to check if the current index is even or odd:

```twig
{% for q in tableItem %}
    {% if loop.index is even %}
        {# output even items #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for q in tableItem %}
    {% if loop.index is odd %}
        {# output odd items #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Though I would rethink this approach. You're tightly coupling your template logic to your styling, which usually results in HTML code that is semantically incorrect. Instead, I'd use a single loop to output the items in order and then user either either a grid to arrange items using [grid-area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area) or, if you're using the Bootstrap flexbox row, rearrange them with [`order-*` classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#order).